# PGFPLOTS labels placement

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to come up with a way to get the labels for my data points to not overlap.
I have been able to change the anchor or the alignment options of all the labels at once but I couldn't make it so I can define the anchor for each individual points as I would with the style of the marks or the labels.

Secondly, I want to get the axis labels out of the way as well.
More precisely, the style I am going for is a right aligned `ylabel` with linebreak yet all the promising answers I have read on axis labels' placement has turned out to have absolutely no effect on the result I get.

Here is a working environment with the first steps through the final result I hope for.

By the way, data comes from https://doi.org/10.2873/725585 for whoever is interested.

[image: problematic]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=french, english]{babel}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, backgrounds}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=8, ymin=0, ymax=5,%
    xlabel near ticks, xlabel={Economic importance},%
    ylabel near ticks, ylabel={Supply risk},%
    axis lines=middle,%
    xtick={0, 2.8, 8},%
    ytick={0, 1.0, 5},%
    unit vector ratio={5 8}
    ]
    \addplot[
      scatter/classes={%
        CRM={mark=*},%
        SRM={fill=gray, mark=*},%
        non={scale=.5,mark=*}},
      scatter, only marks, 
      scatter src=explicit symbolic,
      nodes near coords*={\Label},
      visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \Label}
    ] table [meta=class] {
        EI  SR  class label
        4.9 4.0  CRM  \ce{Ce}
        6.8 2.8  CRM  \ce{Co}
        7.2 0.7  non  \ce{Cr}
        4.0 0.1  SRM  \ce{Cu}
        7.2 0.5  non  \ce{Fe}
        2.9 0.5  non  \ce{H}
        6.4 3.9  CRM  \ce{Ir}
        2.9 3.5  CRM  \ce{La}
        6.9 1.2  CRM  \ce{Mn}
        6.7 0.8  non  \ce{Mo}
        5.7 0.5  SRM  \ce{Ni}
        6.9 2.1  CRM  \ce{Pt}
        6.3 1.6  CRM  \ce{Ti}
    };
    \node (O) at (0,0) {};
    \node (A) at (2.8,0 |- current axis.south) {};
    \node (B) at (2.8,0 |- current axis.north) {};
    \node (C) at (current axis.west |- 0,1.0) {};
    \node (D) at (current axis.east |- 0,1.0) {};
    \node (M) at (A |- C) {};
    \node (X) at (D |- B) {};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \fill[gray!5] (O) rectangle (X);
      \fill[red!20] (M) rectangle (X);
      \draw[dashed] (A)--(B);
      \draw[dashed] (C)--(D);
    \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
I was able to answer my first question by adding the following two lines in the optional arguments of `addplot`:

```
nodes near coords style={anchor=\Anchor},
visualization depends on={value \thisrow{anchor} \as \Anchor}
```

And adding in a fifth column to my table:

```
EI  SR  class label   anchor
4.9 4.0  CRM  \ce{Ce} south
6.8 2.8  CRM  \ce{Co} south
7.2 0.7  non  \ce{Cr} west
4.0 0.1  SRM  \ce{Cu} south
7.2 0.5  non  \ce{Fe} north
2.9 0.5  non  \ce{H}  west
6.4 3.9  CRM  \ce{Ir} south
2.9 3.5  CRM  \ce{La} west
6.9 1.2  CRM  \ce{Mn} south
6.7 0.8  non  \ce{Mo} east
5.7 0.5  SRM  \ce{Ni} east
6.9 2.1  CRM  \ce{Pt} south
6.3 1.6  CRM  \ce{Ti} south
```

I also figured the label placement is bound to the `axis lines=middle` command but that's all I got from that.
`axis lines=left` at least leaves you with a readable chart.

[image]

Comment: Nice. Would be great, if you could add a screenshot for your EDIT. Thank you

Comment: BTW, once you have a satisfying solution, you can put an own answer to your question. This is fine, as: a) each question is exactly 1 problem, b) each answer is 1 concrete solution.

Answer (score 1):

As always, there is more than one way to do it. Here is one. Some comments.

**(A)** There may be a way to achive everything by pgfplots options and commands. However, I find it quite tedious to try out everything. // So, let's apply some `Inventive Thinking` in form of (to be interpreted) `Inventive Principles (IP)`.

**(B)** `Making a copy (of addplot)` + `Taking out (data)`. It's easy to copy the whole `\addplot` statement and mutually delete data. This way you'll get the chance to treat both plots the way you want, i.e. in different ways. // Again, trying out all pgfplots options wasn't fast enough, so let's apply yet another `IP`.

**(C)** `Do a little more (coding)`. So, why not placing the few problematic data points by `\addplot` (done above) AND placing some `\node`s for the missing labels? // To better see them I colored them `red`. You see various ways to anchor or shift labels. Make your choice. (Yes, you could replace everything by a `\foreach`, but code won't be short and may be not that easy to graps.)

```
...
    % ~~~ Inventive Principle: Do a little more (coding) ~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ Poor mans solution: place those labels manually ~~~~~~~
    \node[red,anchor=west] at (7.2,.7){\ce{Cr}};% using standard names
    \node[red,anchor=160]  at (7.2,.5){\ce{Fe}};% using polar notation
...
```

**(D)** Well, putting the axis labels I'll have to leave to you ;-)

**(E)** As an aside, you could also assign the colored areas and the dashed lines to an other `\addplot`, which should probably be the first one. This way you don't need the `\node`s at the end of your code (`IP: Improve by total replacement`).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=french, english]{babel}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, backgrounds}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=8, ymin=0, ymax=5,%
  % ~~~ these puzzle me, so take them away for the moment ~~~~~
%%    xlabel near ticks, 
%    xlabel={Economic importance},%
%%    ylabel near ticks, 
%    ylabel={Supply risk},%
%    axis lines=middle,%
    xtick={0, 2.8, 8},%
    ytick={0, 1.0, 5},%
    unit vector ratio={5 8}
    ]
    % ~~~ See next comment for modifications done ~~~~~~~~~
    \addplot[
      scatter/classes={%
        CRM={mark=*},%
        SRM={fill=gray, mark=*},%
        non={scale=.5,mark=*}},
      scatter, only marks, 
      scatter src=explicit symbolic,
      nodes near coords*={\Label},
      visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \Label}
    ] table [meta=class] {
        EI  SR  class label
        4.9 4.0  CRM  \ce{Ce}
        6.8 2.8  CRM  \ce{Co}
        4.0 0.1  SRM  \ce{Cu}
        6.4 3.9  CRM  \ce{Ir}
        5.7 0.5  SRM  \ce{Ni}
        6.9 2.1  CRM  \ce{Pt}
        6.3 1.6  CRM  \ce{Ti}
    };
    % ~~~ Inventive Principles: Making a copy (of addplot) + Taking out (data) ~~~~~~~~~
    \addplot[
      scatter/classes={%
        CRM={mark=*},%
        SRM={fill=gray, mark=*},%
        non={scale=.5,mark=*}},
      scatter, only marks, 
      scatter src=explicit symbolic,
%      nodes near coords*={\Label},
%      visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \Label},
      label distance=1cm,
    ] table [meta=class] {
        EI  SR  class label
        7.2 0.7  non  \ce{Cr}
        7.2 0.5  non  \ce{Fe}
        6.9 1.2  CRM  \ce{Mn}
        6.7 0.8  non  \ce{Mo}
        2.9 0.5  non  \ce{H}
        2.9 3.5  CRM  \ce{La}
    };
    % ~~~ Inventive Principle: Do a little more (coding) ~~~~~~~~~~~
    % ~~~ Poor mans solution: place those labels manually ~~~~~~~
    \node[red,anchor=west] at (7.2,.7){\ce{Cr}};% using standard names
    \node[red,anchor=160]  at (7.2,.5){\ce{Fe}};% using polar notation
    \node[red,anchor=200]  at (6.9,1.2){\ce{Mn}};
    \node[red,anchor=70 ]  at (6.7,.8){\ce{Mo}};
    \node[red,anchor=250]  at (2.9,.5){\ce{H}};
    \node[red,xshift=3mm]  at (2.9,3.5){\ce{La}};% alternative way to place labels

    % ~~~ unchanged ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (O) at (0,0) {};
    \node (A) at (2.8,0 |- current axis.south) {};
    \node (B) at (2.8,0 |- current axis.north) {};
    \node (C) at (current axis.west |- 0,1.0) {};
    \node (D) at (current axis.east |- 0,1.0) {};
    \node (M) at (A |- C) {};
    \node (X) at (D |- B) {};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \fill[gray!5] (O) rectangle (X);
      \fill[red!20] (M) rectangle (X);
      \draw[dashed] (A)--(B);
      \draw[dashed] (C)--(D);
    \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```